# Need to place an excel file in a Windows folder path from AWS Lambda

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

Is it possible to place or transfer a file to a specific folder in Windows? by a Lambda function running a .NET application.

how this can be achieved?

So far, I have tried creating the file in an S3 bucket path, it has worked fine. But now I am looking at placing the file a local windows shared path.

Comment: AWS Lambda functions are not able to access your computer (or your network). Consider this question... From my own personal computer (not running Windows), how could I place the file in your Windows folder? If you can answer that question then you _might_ be able to do it from a Lambda function but it would require the ability to access your computer/network from the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible not directly from lambda, as lambda function is not intended to be used for transferring though in theory it might be able to but anyway this talk is for another time.

To answer your question, what you have to do is,

1. Place the file on S3, you have already done that
2. Install aws cli on your EC2 host
3. Write logic in your lambda function to invoke ssm run command, the run command command will be an aws cli command that runs from withtin the targeted host and downloads the files from the s3 to the ec2.

Your ec2 host will need to have the ssm agent installed.
I suggest you setup SSM using quicksetup as it is literally pressing 2 buttons in the console.

Generally very simple to do if you have some AWS experience. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, Thank, but I intend to use AWS Batch not EC2, can u give me headsup on this.

Comment: pass the transfer from s3 aws cli command as a command to your pod, add a job ovverride section not sure this is doable? why you dont configure your container to contain the data you want on boot?